# Does bash support arrays?

Tags: arrays, bash

I know that bash supports some kind of list data structure:

```
list="1 2 3"
for i in $list; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

But what about arrays? Does bash have array data structure? And if so, how it would look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36319902/2836621

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: You can man bash and find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash supports one dimensional arrays.

Setting:

```
my_array=(1 2 3)
my_array[0]=0
my_array[2]=2
```

Retrieving:

```
echo ${my_array[1]}
2

echo ${my_array[@]}     # all values
0 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different notations for arrays in bash.

You can define an array like `name[index]=value`, or like `name=(val1 val2 val3)`, or explicitly declare an array using `declare -a ARRAYNAME`. You can reference individual elements of an array with `${name[index]}` or the whole array with `${name[@]}`.